# GroupSequenceProvider on Child form entities in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a parent form and a child which is of type collection, which can have adds/removes.

I need the GroupSequenceProviderInterface on both the parent and the child entities, because my validation is dynamic based on the form data.

Both forms have dynamic validation groups, which I add in the controller based on form input.

GroupSequence works great on the parent form, ever with complex validation groups.

The child seems to be setup correctly and the group is definitely being added, however getGroupSequence on the child element is never called.

This makes me wonder whether it is even possible to have dynamic validation on Child Entities. Can symfony handle groups in a hierarchy?

I am using symfony 2.3

**Is there a way to have GroupSequence validation on child form entities?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here was actually my child entities were not being validated because they did not have the Valid annotation.

```
// parent entity class

/**
* @Assert\Valid
*/
public $childEntity;
```